# Get users Mac address if connected to WiFi network (MikroTik)

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address, hotspot, mikrotik-routeros

I would like to log the users Mac address to a database hosted on a web server. I was wondering if there is a variable I can use like for example `$mac-address` which will replace it with the users mac address.

I think of using that variable in a hidden field and when the form is submitted I'll log the info to a database.

Is this even possible? Cause I know in the status page under the hotspot folder, you see the mac address of the device connected.

I also tried using `$(mac)` nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Routers always log the MAC address to whatever system logger the router is using upon a DHCP request, so it's fairly straightforward from there by searching the system log at set intervals with `regex` since the MACs will always be in the same hexadecimal format of `<A-F><0-9>:...:...:...:...:...`, then piping it to a database or using whatever way you wish to assign the variable then import.

Answer (score 0):

Several  ways to achieve that, in my personal preferred order:

- Log the Wifi activity and send it to a syslog server, wich will log data on a database. You will have exact connect/disconnect times of everything connecting to your AP.
- Use a C# (for example) program with Mikrotik API to "listen" for incoming MAC addresses, and log them in a database.
- Query your Mikrotik AP using SNMP or API to get the list of connected MAC-addresses: you'll get snapshots of connected people every minute for example.

Comment: But it is already built in...for example if you use the built in hotspot feature...in the status page it shows the MAC address just by using a simple `tag`. I was wondering if it is possible to have that on other pages, that are hosted elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, syslog is the easier way to do that.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to work, it is supposed to replace the tag with the Mac address but it doesn't..is there a way to turn it on?